# Manage div scroll bar using select box option

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

How we can manage parent div scroll bar using inner select box select option.
Basically I have added a scroll bar on DIV and I want to see all the records of a select box.
I have used the following code for this but it's not working as expected.

```
 $('#selectLst').change(function()
                {
                 var divscrollvalue = ( parseInt(this.selectedIndex))*17;
                 $('#selectListDiv').scrollTop(divscrollvalue );

                });

        });
```

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Try `$('#selectLst').on('input change propertychange',function()`... `change` doesn't work on all elements

Comment: Hi @myfunkyside, the function is working fine but I think the value of scrollTop is not appropriate.

Comment: You can use `console.log(divscrollvalue);`, `console.log(this.selectedIndex);`, etc. to see if all the values are as expected (you can read out the console.logs in *DevTools*, *Console* tab - *F12* on Win). If you still can't figure it out, I second NicoShultz's comment (actually, I second that either way, answering a question like yours with too little information is really difficult as is already evident).